# Is there a way to get a single entire View from ListView's position?

Tags: android, listview, view

I got a ListView, an adapter and, of course, and Activity that manage it all.

how can I get a view at some position from my Activity to change something from Activity?
I know I can make changes and then do `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, but I want an entire view back to my Activity

for example:

```
private void changeText(int index){
View view=adapter.giveMeBackMyView(index); //that's what I'm trying to find
TextView tv=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listTextView);
tv.setText("changed");

}
```

Comment: see getFirstVisubleItem, it is the first child view

Comment: you can get all the visible view's but listview re-uses this views and changing them this will get u in trouble. As in when you will scroll change will be gone or other item will be changed

Comment: did you try using adapter.getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent).but you should make changes in the data object also as soon as you change in the view so that the changes become permanent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this here:    setAdapter to the ListView first, than `yourListView.getItemAtPosition(index);`
or `yourAdapter.getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
adapter.getView(index, null, null);
```

Just be aware you are short-cutting the adapter/view system. This is not a good idea because the view you are asking for may not actually exist in the listview. Remember a listview can contain millions of items. Those don't all actually exist. There are just a few visible views, and android recycles them as you scroll. So may need to re-think how you are approaching this problem, with that in mind.

Comment: Greg, say I have a list view, with cells, and in the cells are many buttons. Using "onClick", I get to routine clickedFun(View v). That view is **only the button**.  I then need to get the "whole" cell.  (And indeed using getTag, get the "holder".)  So that I can, say, change things in the cell.  How else could it be done!??  Thank you for the great tip here BTW!